# How to return the data as well as the http status code of the url being curled?

Tags: php, curl

I have following code

```
function curl($url) {
    $options = Array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

How to return the data as well as the http status code of the url being curled?

Comment: `return [$data, $httpCode];`

Answer (score 0):

Common way to return a set of data from a function is to use an **array**, either numerical or associative. This can be done like:

```
curl($url) {

    // other codes here

    return array($data, $httpCode);
}

// or 

curl($url) {

    // other codes here

    return array(
        'data' => $data, 
        'statusCode' => $httpCode
    );
}
```